# HTML data extraction using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to extract mobile specification data from nokia developer website      http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/Nokia_Asha_308/ using Jsoup.
How can I obtain data for each of the sub-category like  'Camera Features', 'Graphic Formats'etc. separately.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Nokiareviews {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SQLException,    InterruptedException {
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/Nokia_Asha_308/").timeout(1000*1000).get();
Elements content = doc.select("div#accordeonContainer");
for (Element spec : content) {
System.out.println(spec.text());
}
}

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look closer, you'll see that every category is a `<div>` with `class=accordeonContainer`, its title is in a `h2` (under that) and the subcategory list is under a `<dl>` with a `"clearfix"` CSS class:

```
<div class="accordeonContainer accordeonExpanded">
    <h2 class=" accordeonTitle "><span>Multimedia</span></h2>
    <div class="accordeonContent" id="Multimedia" style="display: block;">
        <dl class="clearfix">
            <dt>Camera Resolution</dt>
            <dd>1600 x 1200 pixels  </dd>
                ...    
            <dt>Graphic Formats</dt>
            <dd>BMP, DCF, EXIF, GIF87a, GIF89a, JPEG, PNG, WBMP </dd>
            ...
        </dl>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can pick a list of elements of a certain type (say `elm`) and of a given CSS class (say `clazz`) using:

```
Elements elms = doc.select("elm.clazz");
```

Then, in short, a code to extract the information you mentioned, could be something in the lines of:

```
public class Nokiareviews {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.developer.nokia.com/Devices/Device_specifications/Nokia_Asha_308/")
                .timeout(1000 * 1000).get();
        Elements content = doc.select("div.accordeonContainer");
        for (Element spec : content) {
            Elements h2 = spec.select("h2.accordeonTitle");
            System.out.println(h2.text());

            Elements dl = spec.select("dl.clearfix");
            Elements dts = dl.select("dt");
            Elements dds = dl.select("dd");

            Iterator<Element> dtsIterator = dts.iterator();
            Iterator<Element> ddsIterator = dds.iterator();
            while (dtsIterator.hasNext() && ddsIterator.hasNext()) {
                Element dt =  dtsIterator.next();
                Element dd =  ddsIterator.next();
                System.out.println("\t\t" + dt.text() + "\t\t" + dd.text());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If using maven, make sure you add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```